# Jenkins running Protractor tests creates no reports

Tags: batch-file, selenium, jenkins, protractor

I have a Jenkins project that firstly runs a batch file that runs a selenium server for Protractor to use. It then runs a second batch file in order to run the tests via Protractor.

Running these tests works fine if I execute the batch files manually, and generates a report via Mocha. However if I run these batch files via Jenkins, no reports are created.

This is my config:

```
var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    rootElement:     '[ng-app]',

    allScriptsTimeout: 80000,

    // resultJsonOutputFile: './Report.json', // adds a JSON file from protractor test reults


    framework: 'mocha',
    mochaOpts: {
        reporter:        'mochawesome-screenshots',
        reporterOptions: {
            reportDir:            'reports/' + today + '/',
            reportName:           'DOCS Dev QA Automation' + today, // TODO: Enter desired report name
            reportTitle:          'DOCS Dev QA Automation', // TODO: Enter desired report title
            takePassedScreenshot: false,
            clearOldScreenshots:  true
        },
        timeout:         60000
    },

    specs: [ 'yadda_runner.js' ],

    capabilities: {
        browserName:   'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ '--lang=en',
                '--window-size=1280,1024' ]
        }
        //browserName: 'firefox'
    },

    // Runs on start up and logs in to Docs
    onPrepare: function() {



        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.driver.get(browser.params.baseUrl);

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('sign_in')).click();
        browser.driver.switchTo().frame('loginframe');

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('userName')).sendKeys(browser.params.login.username);
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('verify_user_btn')).click();

        // TODO: see if there is a better way to wait for this, unfortunately the browser.driver.wait isElementPresent doesn't seem to work
        browser.driver.sleep(2000); // wait for password field to be visible

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys(browser.params.login.password);
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('btnSubmit')).click();

        // Wait for login to complete
        return browser.driver.wait(function () {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                return /projects/.test(url);  // tests that the current URL contains the word 'projects'
            });
        }, 60000);

    },

    // Runs on exit and logs out of Docs
    onComplete: function() {
        browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.header__control.header__control--profile')).click();
        browser.driver.findElement(by.css('body > div > div > header > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > flyout > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > ul > li > a')).click();

            return browser.driver.wait(function () {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                return /session/.test(url); // tests that the current URL contains the word 'session'
            });
        }, 60000);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was the fact that Jenkins was running as a service in the background. When ran as a service it is not possible for protractor to open up chrome in order to do the testing.

Protractor wasn't creating any reports because it never finished the tests since it never started them. When I was running the batch file it was not running as a service because my actions were not a service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following things:

- Are you running Jenkins as a server or locally ?
- If running locally is it a service or a war file that you are running?
- Does Jenkins have **permissions** to write files to your current directory?
- Have you set your environment variables correctly?

Your current issue, I think is mostly that Jenkins does not have permission to write files(create reports) in your directory . Please check that!

Comment: Well its not Jenkins that is creating these reports, Protractor should be creating them. Does that still require Jenkins to have file writing permission? If so what do I need to do to grant it permission?

Comment: To expand on the other questions: Jenkins is running on a remote windows slave that is running it as a windows service. This project currently has no environment variables, however I am struggling to know how to use these correctly, as in: I can set them in the Properties content under inject environment variables but I don't know how I then use them when it comes to the Build